# JDBC: how to perform functions inside a prepared statement?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

With this query

```
  INSERT INTO `schema`.`table` (`col1`, `col2`) 
  VALUES ('value1', unhex(sha2("value2", 256)));
```

how to prepare a statement for the jdbc driver with one value produced by those functions?

```
 preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("insert into schema.table values (?, ?)");
```

Comment: Try replacing the values (`value1`/`value2`) in your original SQL with bind variables (question marks); it should work: `VALUES (?, unhex(sha2(?, 256)))`

Comment: These are **database** functions you want to call, right?

Comment: @Jan yes they are db sql functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following format to get the job done.

```
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("insert into schema.table values (?, unhex(sha2(?,256)))");

preparedStatement.setString(1, "value1");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "value2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("insert into schema.table values (?, unhex(sha2(?, 256)))");
```